# Usage of javascript closures for adding two numbers

Tags: javascript, closures

How would I use a closure to achieve this???

addTogether(2)(3);

I also need the same function to return normal addition as in addTogether(2,3) returns 5.

Comment: I have to ask, for what possible reason could you need to do this? I am intrigued by what the potential use case could/would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
function addTogether(a, b) {
  if (b === undefined) {
    return function (b) { return a + b; }
  } else {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

However, returning a function or number will be confusing (at best) for your users. I would suggest always returning a function, but allowing it to be called without parameters (only slightly better):

```
function addTogether(a, b) {
  if (b === undefined) {
    return function (c) { return a + c; }
  } else {
    return function ( ) { return a + b; }
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: `b == null` handles `b === undefined || b === null`

Comment: Nope, the only time `==` will return `true` when one of the operands is `null` or `undefined` is if the other operand is also `null` or `undefined`... `0 == null; // false` It's just about the only time I use `==` in real code. I agree though that the `null` check is probably not needed.

Comment: @squint huh, you're right. I assumed `==` would treat 0 as falsy enough to match null, but apparently not.

Comment: Yeah, that's the trouble with `==`. Its algorithm is too complex to provide an intuitive understanding. The `==` to check `null` and `undefined` is just too handy to pass up though!